# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop-error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a login form and I got this error.

```
export default function LoginScreen(props) {
        const [Submit, setSubmit] = React.useState('')
        const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
        const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
        const [valuePass, setValuePass] = React.useState('')
        const [valueUsername, setValueUsername] = React.useState('')
        const [secureTextEntry, setSecureTextEntry] = React.useState(true)
    
        const toggleSecureEntry = () => {
            setSecureTextEntry(!secureTextEntry)
        }
        const AlertIcon = (props) => <Icon {...props} name='alert-circle-outline' />
        const renderIcon = (props) => (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={toggleSecureEntry}>
                <Icon {...props} name={secureTextEntry ? 'eye-off' : 'eye'} />
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
    
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Login</Text>
                <Input
                    placeholder='Username'
                    value={valueUsername}
                    style={{ width: windowWidth - 50, borderRadius: 16 }}
                    onChangeText={(nextValue) => setValueUsername(nextValue)}
                    size='large'
                />
                <View style={{ height: 15 }}></View>
                <Input
                    style={{ width: windowWidth - 50, borderRadius: 16 }}
                    size='large'
                    value={valuePass}
                    placeholder='Password'
                    caption='Should contain at least 8 symbols'
                    accessoryRight={renderIcon}
                    captionIcon={AlertIcon}
                    secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
                    onChangeText={(nextValue) => setValuePass(nextValue)}
                />
                <View style={{ marginTop: 25 }}>
                    <Button
                        style={{ borderRadius: 15 }}
                        onPress={setSubmit(true)}
                        size='large'
                    >
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Can anyone explain why this error occurs??

I am new to react-native.

Ignore this(just for adding volume)==I have to add some useless sentences because StackOverflow gives me `'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'`(So frustrated with this stackoverflow error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your onPress prop

```
onPress={setSubmit(true)}
```

Everything between the curly braces is evaluated immediately. Because of this, the setSubmit function is called in every render loop.

By wrapping the function with an arrow function, the evaluated code will result in a function that can be called whenever the user clicks on the button.

So it should be

```
onPress={()=>{setSubmit(true)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Button's onPress prop you should pass a function instead of passing directly an instance. What i mean is this;

```
<Button onPress={() => setSubmit(true)} />
```

Do same with `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` also.

What happens there is that `onPress` is checked when the component is mounted and inside that you are chnaging the state again and again as you are calling `setSubmit`, but when you pass a function and there you do the stuff, it waits for the click as `onPress` takes a callback function to be called when a button is pressed.