# React Native Axios fetching data from url error

Tags: axios, react-native

import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, StatusBar, ScrollView, View, Text, TextInput, Button, Alert  } from 'react-native';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class Main extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state={
ifscCode:"",
detail:{}
}
}

```
  ifscSearch = () => {
    const tha = this;
    x = `https://ifsc.razorpay.com/${this.state.ifscCode}`
    console.log(x);
  axios.get(`https://ifsc.razorpay.com/${this.state.ifscCode}`)
    .then(function (response) {
    tha.setState({detail:response.data})
    console.log(response);
     })

    .catch(function (error) {
     // handle error
     console.log(error);
     })
    .then(function () {
     // always executed
     });
    }


render() {
    return (
        <>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <SafeAreaView>
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.maincnt}>

                    <View style={styles.inpcnt}>
                    <TextInput style={styles.txtinp} maxLength={11} placeholder='ifsc code search' onChange={(e)=>this.setState({ifscCode:e.target.value})} />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.btncnt}>
                        <Button title='Search' style={styles.btn} onClick={this.ifscSearch()} />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.listcnt}>
                        <Text>BANK: {this.state.detail.BANK}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
        </>
    )
}
```

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
maincnt:{
flex:1,
margin: 10,
backgroundColor: 'white'
},
inpcnt:{
marginTop: 20,
},
btncnt:{
marginTop: 20,
},
listcnt:{
marginTop: 20
},
txtinp:{
width: 350,
height: 50,
borderRadius: 25,
borderWidth: 2,
borderColor: 'indigo',
alignSelf: 'center',
padding: 10
},
btn:{
width: 100,
height: 70,
alignSelf: 'center'
},
listcnt:{
marginTop: 50,
alignContent: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center'
}

});

Comment: I am new to react native and backend too plss help to resolve

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

You are having an error here

```
onClick={this.ifscSearch()}
```

please check out the below link to solve this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66149805/10562665

Also I see a little type error here as well

```
tha.setState({detail:response.data})
```

change **tha** to **this**

Please tell us more in details what you actually need.